# Setting update interval for threats tab in JMC

Tags: java, profiling, jmc

I'm trying to see the stack traces of some live threads via the Threads tab in Java Mission Control. This is possible by selecting a thread and then looking at the "Stack traces for selected threads" section.

My problem is that the screen refreshes every 3 seconds and I can't find the option to make that interval longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Update interval for thread stacks [ms]" preference directly under Window -> Preferences -> Java Mission Control -> JMX Console, could that be it?